# Can't make virtual host work

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.
No matter what I do - can't make virtual hosts work, everything is routed to the configuration defined in **000-default.conf**.
I've got the following sites enabled:

**dev.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
    ServerName dev.example.com
    DocumentRoot "a valid path"
    ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8090
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
    RemoteIPInternalProxy localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course, the domain was changed to `example.com` and I removed the real file path for the document root.
Both files appear `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, and if add some garbage in dev.conf Apache doesn't start so I know it reads it.
The DNS is setup correctly - nslookup for dev.example.com and example.com return the same correct IP (tested from an external network).
I've had a similar setup with Debian and Apache 2.2, and it worked just fine (don't have it anymore, can't compare).

Any request I send is routed to **000-default.conf**, dev.example.com or anything-that's-valid.example.com, since I don't have a `DocumentRoot` directive (I tried adding it as well) due to the fact that I'm redirecting to the https version, I'm getting the default `/var/www/html`.
This path does not appear in any config file and is probably compiled in as the default value for `DocumentRoot`.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make the **dev.conf** virtual host work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
```

Should be

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: It happens to all of us. ;)